# Decimal round off - I'm getting 2.01506160000328E14

Tags: java

I'm getting 2.01506160000328E14 ----- I need this value should be 20150616.0000328

From network I'm reading data as read double(in,10) ... Double value I'm getting E14. I want to convert as a normal number as above format

Comment: Please provide more context to this question. What you tried, what you are getting, what you are expecting and where you are failing, ideally with a small program. As is, this question will be closed.

Comment: ...and by the way, storing dates decimally encoded in a float seems like a bad idea.

Comment: @aioobe: Works for Excel. :-) Mind you, Excel does it differently from the above.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, ok. I really don't want to know more about that topic (I need to hold on to the little faith I have left in Excel).

Comment: @aioobe: :-) Don't worry, it's not as bad as it sounds: It's days since Jan 1 1900 at midnight. So the whole number is how many days, and the fractional part is how much of the day (e.g., the time). `14.5` is  Jan 14th at noon.

Comment: I edit the post... Please check

Comment: Ok, phew.. That's far better than `year*10000 + month*100 + day + hours*.001 + minutes*.00001 + seconds*.0000001` :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it that you want to print out a double to a string?
20150616.0000328 should be 2.01506160000328E7 but not 2.01506160000328E14

code as follows, is that what you want?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Double d = 20150616.0000328;
    System.out.println("exponential = " + d);

    String formatMask = "0.################################################";
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(formatMask);

    System.out.println("normal number=" + df.format(d));
}
```

result:

exponential = 2.01506160000328E7

normal number=20150616.0000328

Comment: @t.j crowder : exactly... Thank you so much...

Comment: Diufanman thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

> Double value I'm getting E14. I want to convert as a normal number as above format

It **is** a normal number. What you're seeing is just a string representation of it in [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation).

> I need this value should be 20150616.0000328

The number `2.01506160000328E14` is `201506160000328`. If you want `20150616.0000328`, you'll have to divide by a million.

That said, I would **strongly** recommend that if this is a date/time as it seems to be, you read it as *text* and parse it.